# Is there any tool which can do minified js to normal?

Tags: javascript, minify

I have taken one min.js online which too much log to copy whenever i tried to copy past on online tool my pc got hang.
i am using following online tool : 
http://www.jspretty.com/

Is there any other tool on which instead of copy past we can upload file directly??

Comment: What are you actually looking for? A minified --> normal tool, or a normal --> minified one where you can upload a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use Google Chrome Developer tools Pretty Print option for this,

**Chrome DevTools > Sources > Pretty Print**

[image: Chrome DevTools > Sources > Pretty Print]

[Read More Information](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pretty-print)

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple solution if you're using Eclipse

1. Open Eclipse
2. Open the minified .js file
3. Press: Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: This does nothing in Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0)